# Geometry Node : Point Instance with normal

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm using Blender 3.0.0 alpha.

I want to copy object to line (point instance) with maintaining object's normal, but I can't find how to it. Someone said using Align Rotation to Vector, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: just rotate your object in edit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for example, you want the instance's Z axis to point down the line:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works very well :)

Comment: Hello Betts! I started to use new Blender 3.0 alpha, and found 'Align Rotation to Vector' and other nodes are removed! So is it still possible to rotate the instance with new nodes? Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since normals is a face corner data, you cannot get normals from mesh structure that doesn't have faces. To rotate your objects manually, insert node **point rotate** between generation of points and **point instance**:

[image]

Or rotate the whole structure afterwards using **transform**:

[image]